# AngularFireAuth: VerifyPasswordResetCode Returning (auth/invalid-action-code)

Tags: angular, firebase

I am currently trying to validate an oobCode coming from my Firebase application in order to reset a password for an account. I am using Angular 13 for this project.

This is the ngInit that read in the query string sent through the email:

```
var routeSnap = this.activatedRoute.snapshot;

if(!routeSnap.queryParams) {
    this.router.navigate(['']);
}

this.mode = String(routeSnap.queryParams['mode']);
this.actionCode = String(routeSnap.queryParams['oobcode']);
    
this.authService.VerifyPasswordResetCode(this.actionCode)
    .then(() => {
        this.actionCodeChecked = true;
    })
    .catch(e => {
        // Invalid or expired action code. Ask user to try to
        // reset the password again.
        alert(e);
        this.router.navigate(['']);
    });
```

The authService method is as such (afAuth is of type `AngularFireAuth`):

```
VerifyPasswordResetCode(code: string) {
    return this.afAuth.verifyPasswordResetCode(code)
}
```

The exact error message is `FirebaseError: Firebase: The action code is invalid. This can happen if the code is malformed, expired, or has already been used. (auth/invalid-action-code).`

1. Debugging through the DevTools also shows that the exact oobCode is pulled from the query string.
2. The oobCode coming from Firebase should not be expired since I am hitting the verify immediately on the page load, and I click the email link as soon as it hits the inbox.
3. This is the first time the code would ever be used, so it should not be a security failure.

If anyone has any idea why this could be failing, please let me know! Thank you :)